# Excel Pivot Table data source after file name change, refers to previous file name

Tags: excel, datasource, rename, pivot-table

I have an excel workbook with several pivot tables referring to data contained in the workbook. All data referred to by the pivot tables are contained within this workbook ("Version 1").

I would like to rename this workbook as "version 2", but when I rename the workbook, all the pivot tables refer to the "version 1" data. I want the pivot tables to refer to the data in "version 2".

I have tried several combinations of option settings, but I cannot find a combination of settings that automatically changes the pivot table source references to the newly named "version 2".

I understand that could write a vba script to solve this issue, but I want to know if there is a non-vba solution.

Comment: Before changing the name do you have 2 files or 1?  If 1, I am surprised you are able to create a Pivot Table that has a reference to the workbook name.  It should all be relative just with sheets.  Can you update your question with a picture of the Pivot Table Data Source?  Or at least paste address here.

Answer (score 3):

I had this very issue (using Excel 2013). After simple file copy\rename and opening copied\renamed file, excel started complaining about security (external data source) and i was unable to refresh PivotTables (message "cannot open PivotTable source file xxx" where xxx was the old file name)

**1) How to fix broken workbook:**

Activate pivot table (put cursor inside) so that 'PIVOTTABLE TOOLS' ribbon is shown. Click ANALYZE and *Change data source* button. Put carrent inside textbox (do not use arrow keys!) and delete file name including surrounding [] characters. Refresh pivot table.
Do this with every PivotTable in workbook.
Done.

**2) How to get rid of this nasty issue for good:**

I opened original\fixed workbook. Activate 'PIVOTTABLE TOOLS\ANALYZE' ribbon. Click 'Options' button (left side of ribbon in my Excel), switch to Data tab and uncheck "Save source data with file". Ignore warning (just OK). Now i can copy\rename file as i wish and had no issues at all...

3) Workaround (just to be safe) - never make copies of workbook in Windows Explorer or other file manager but use *Save as* functionality in Excel - just open the workbook you want to make copy of and use *Save as*

Comment: Thanks for the tips... (1) works but is a big pain.  (2) works but doesn't get preserved, so I have to set it again every time I open the file.  (3) doesn't work for me. As soon as I use "Save As" all my pivot tables start referring to the old file. I'm on "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013".

Comment: That's strange. (3) definitely works for me. Make sure definition of data region in original file doesn't contain file name before you use 'Save as'...

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the following post, I implemented the mentioned VBA solution.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43bf5110-dfad-40e5-a71c-e9736da6fbc2/data-source-path-in-pivot-table-changes-to-absolute-on-its-own?forum=excel

The VBA-Code is the following:

```
Sub Update_PivotTables_Source()
Dim currWS As Worksheet
Dim currPT As PivotTable
 On Error Resume Next
 For Each currWS In Application.Worksheets
    For Each currPT In currWS.PivotTables
        currPT.SourceData = Mid(currPT.SourceData, InStr(1,currPT.SourceData, "!") + 1)
   Next currPT
 Next currWS
End Sub
```

All other non-VBA solutions mentioned in the post didn't work for me.

Comment: This above VBA code will work if the pivot table is on the same sheet as the data, which is rare. It will also work if the source is a named range. If those don't apply I suggest replacing the "!" in the above code with "]" which will retain the sheet name but remove the filename of the reference. Then put "'" & in front of the Mid function. The completed line will look like this.
currPT.SourceData = "'" & Mid(currPT.SourceData, InStr(1, currPT.SourceData, "]") + 1)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the format of the file .xlsx.

I solved the issue as below:

1. Save your file in .xls but not with the same name that your .xlsx file
2. Click on continue on the compatibility checker pop up
3. Click on YES on the Pop up asking about to recalculate all formulas because of the earlier version of Excell.
4. Maye be some data source have to be redone after that if you have multiple pivot. After when saving and save as, it works. It keep the data zone as a source for the pivot.

As soon you switch to a .xlsx the issue come back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to convert my broken xlsx pivots this way, but I rebuilt my entire workbook from scratch in xls format, and now it works.  I can save-as and my pivot tables still continue reading from the current (newly saved-as) file.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the solution:

> I didn't seen any real resolution that was simple on this thread so
>   I'm posting. This method seemed to work for me.
>
> In Windows Explorer, right-click on the file and select copy. Then
>   Paste into the same folder. A new file will be created as 'filename
>   COPY'. You can then just re-edit the filename as desired there (ie.
>   with a new date). You can then update whatever data tables you have
>   and the pivot tables will be referencing those tables internal to that
>   document and not the old file.
>
> Thank goodness that worked!
>
> Hope it helps anyone else out there!
>
> Phil

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/43bf5110-dfad-40e5-a71c-e9736da6fbc2/data-source-path-in-pivot-table-changes-to-absolute-on-its-own?forum=excel&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

I think I have may have found a solution.  This is what worked for me:

1. Opened the file with the corrupted pathing
2. Open the file that the corrupted workbook is referencing
3. Then delete the data sheets that the pivot tables should be referencing (within the corrupted workbook)
4. Move (don't copy) the data sheets from the file that the corrupted pivot tables are referencing into the corrupted file. Now your pivot tables should be referencing only sheets within the workbook.
5. Create a blank sheet in the formerly corrupted file
6. Move (not copy) all sheets except for the blank one created before to a new workbook.
7. Save locally to your machine.
8. Upload to your desired location.

After doing all of these steps the problem has not returned.  And I am able to freely move this workbook around using Save As or copy within windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Click Analyze--> Change Data Source->Table/Range : update the excel file name and/or folder source if the file has been moved.

This should resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to your source tab/table, click on design in table tools and give it a unique table name in the top left corner above resize table, e.g. "data". Then click into your pivot table-analyze-change data source and type in the name you just gave to that table, in our case "data" and confirm. The key here is that your pivot table only refers to the table name without the file name. Repeat for all of your other pivots and now your pivots should update regardless of what your file name is.

Answer (score 0):

I found another one!!!

1. Unzip the XLS or XLSM file into a directory
2. Find XL/Connections.XML file and preferably open with Notepad++
3. In the <**Connection**> node, look for **deleted**="1".  Change that to "0".
4. Note the **Name** field contents.
5. Save the xml file.
6. Zip the directory contents (not the directory) into AnyNewFileName.XLSM (or XLS)
7. Open this new spreadsheet
8. Look in Data/Queries and Connections, and look for the **Name** from step 4
9. Delete that Query or connection.